# Dynamic domain apply while other field's value changed - odoo

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

```py
class procurement(models.Model)
    _name="procurement"

    procurement_line_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='procurement.line', inverse_name='procurement_id', string='Procurement Lines')
    global_procurement = fields.Boolean("Global Procurement",default=True)

class procurement_line(models.Model)
    _name="procurement.line"

    procurement_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='procurement', string='Procurement')
    warehouse_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.warehouse', string='Warehouse')

class stock_warehouse(models.Model)
    _name="stock.warehouse"

    is_default_warehouse = fields.Boolean(string="Is Default Warehouse?",default=False)
```

[image]

If global_procurement is True then I want to load only default warehouses in procurement lines otherwise I want to load all warehouses. So how could I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may try with following way.

1. Pass value in context. For example:

   ```
   <field name="warehouse_id" 
          context="{'global_procurement': parent.global_procurement}"/>
   ```
2. Check context value *name_search()* of *stock.warehouse* object. For example:

   ```
   @api.model
   def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
       if self._context and self._context.get('global_procurement'):
           default_list = [1,2,3] # set your logic to search list of default warehouse
           return self.browse(default_list).name_get()
       return super(Warehouse, self).name_search(name=name, args=new_args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
   ```

I have written answer in air. I didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I will try it and update you.

Comment: Still not implemented your solution, let me try it.

Comment: Your solution worked but I have done it little bit differently, use your idea ;)

Comment: Because name_search will reflect through the entire odoo for that model. So it will increase bit more load. So I done it differently. Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by just defining domain in field (idea is taken from then @Odedra's answer).

```
<field name="warehouse_id" required="1" domain="[('field_name','=',parent.global_procurement)]" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_quick_create':True, 'no_create_edit':True}" />
```